# web application in dojo

Tags: dojo

does a dojo application supports all the web browsers if java script is used in it?

Comment: yes its working in IE6 but not in mozilla and IE7..

Comment: Dojo (as well as other reputable libraries) will do its part to normalize and handle cross-browser inconsistencies and quirks while you're under the umbrella of its functions, but that doesn't change the fact that code *you* write might still do something that not all browsers agree with.  A JS toolkit's job is to assist and ease development; it's not a magical cure-all (it's physically impossible for it to be).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Dojo 1.6 release notes](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/releasenotes/1.6.html).

Supported browsers:

- Firefox 3.6
- Safari 4/Safari 5 and Chrome 8
- IE6, IE7, IE8
- Opera 10.50 and later (Dojo core only)

So, not "all" browsers are supported, but the most popular ones are.